# MySQL conditional concatenate based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I'm stumped on a proper query to get an output based on multiple columns and the conditions in those columns:

```
   a  b  c
1  x     x
2  x  x  
3  x
```

I would like the results to output, based on where the x's are in columns a, b and c:

```
1 a,c
2 a,b
3 a
```

Is this possible to do in mysql? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CONCAT_WS` function ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)) and some `IF` statements.

```
SELECT tn.ID,
CONCAT_WS(
  ',',
  IF(tn.a='x','a',null),
  IF(tn.b='x','b',null),
  IF(tn.c='x','c',null)
) as result
FROM TableName tn;
```

Comment: I just leaned something.. Never used CONCAT_WS before.. this is definitely a good use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL` function for that ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)). For example:

```
SELECT a, IFNULL(b, c) FROM table_name;
```

It will select `a` for every case and conditionally b or c, depending on it's value (it have to be `not null`). But I'm afraid you cannot do more than that.